# How do I animate my stickman's legs and make it look like he's walking on the same place

Tags: javascript, canvas, jquery-animate

I am new to canvas and I want my stickman to move his legs as if he is walking. My knowledge is very limited. I've received this code as a template to use, the only task I had to do was add a sword to him. As a challenge, I want him to walk. I have tried many solutions but they all required CSS which is not the case for my code here. Other sources weren't as helpful such as Youtube videos because they did not explain what they were doing.

```js
function drawSpartacus(el, x, y, facing) {
  const c = el.getContext("2d");

  // set our drawing style
  c.lineWidth = 2;
  c.lineCap = "round";
  c.lineJoin = "round"
  c.strokeStyle = "#000";

  if (x == null) x = 100;
  if (y == null) y = 150;

  // the arms and the legs look the same
  drawLimbs(c, x, y)            // legs
  drawLimbs(c, x, y - 40)         // arms

  // body is just a line
  line(c, x, y - 40, x, y - 80)     // body

  // head is a circle with eyes and a smile
  circle(c, x, y - 100, 20)       // head
  drawFace(c, x, y - 100, facing) // face


  // helpful functions start here
  function drawLimbs(c, x, y) {
    line(c, x - 20, y, x, y - 40)
    line(c, x + 20, y, x, y - 40)
  }

  function drawFace(c, x, y, facing) {
    // if the `facing` parameter is not given, the stick figure will face towards us
    if (facing == null) facing = 90;

    // make sure the `facing` parameter is between 0 and 360
    facing = facing % 360; // that's like the mathematical remainder after a division
    if (facing < 0) facing += 360;

    if (facing > 180) return;  // facing away from us, don't draw a face

    // we'll fake the turning of the face by shifting the eyes and the smile by an offset of up to 10 pixels
    let faceOffset = 0;
    if (facing <= 180) {
      faceOffset = (facing - 90) / 9;
    }

    circle(c, x - 7 - faceOffset, y - 5, 1)  // 7 is distance from center, 5 is how high the eyes are from the head's center, 1 is eye size
    circle(c, x + 7 - faceOffset, y - 5, 1)

    // decrease the smile size here
    const smileSize = 70; // size of smile in degrees of angle; 360 would be a full circle
    const startAngle = rad(90 - smileSize / 2 - 2 * faceOffset)
    const endAngle = rad(90 + smileSize / 2 - 2 * faceOffset)
    arc(c, x - faceOffset, y, 12, startAngle, endAngle) // 12 is the radius of the smile circle
  }

  // draw a line on canvas context `c`, from point x1,y1 to point x2,y2
  function line(c, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(x1, y1);
    c.lineTo(x2, y2);
    c.stroke();
  }

  // draw a circle on canvas context `c`, centered on x,y, with radius r
  // also fill the circle with white (so it's not transparent)
  function circle(c, x, y, r) {
    c.beginPath()
    c.fillStyle = "#fff"
    c.arc(x, y, r, 0, 6.3, false); // 6.3 is bigger than 2π so the arc will be a whole circle
    c.fill()
    c.stroke()
  }


  // draw an arc on canvas context `c`, cenetered on x,y, with radius r, from angleStart to angleEnd
  function arc(c, x, y, r, angleStart, angleEnd) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, r, angleStart, angleEnd, false)
    c.stroke();
  }

  // convert from degrees to radians
  function rad(x) {
    return x * Math.PI / 180;
  }





  //grip
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(115, 110);
  c.lineTo(125, 110);
  c.lineTo(125, 115);
  c.lineTo(115, 115);
  c.closePath();
  c.stroke();
  c.fillStyle = "#654321";
  c.fill();


  //blade
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(125, 110);
  c.lineTo(145, 109);
  c.lineTo(148, 112.5);
  c.lineTo(145, 116);
  c.lineTo(125, 115);
  c.closePath();
  c.stroke();
  c.fillStyle = "#c0c0c0";      //This fills colour on the closed path above.
  c.fill();

  //cross guard
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(125, 105);
  c.lineTo(125, 120);
  c.stroke();

}
```

Comment: So, what you are doing in this code is basically painting some circles and lines and arcs. In order the make it walk, you need to use for example two divs with id of "leg1"  and "leg2". And you should place those legs' positions relative to your stick body. And then you should animate their rotation with css.

Comment: Is there a method only using canvas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations